# Select all records between two datetime format

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-format

I have this query, i need to select all records between two dates, the mysql table is a datetime format.

I tried this but it didn't work.

```
select * from cdr
 WHERE calldate BETWEEN '2012-12-01' AND '2012-12-03';
```

Comment: " but it didn't work." Can you be more specific? What was the error message or undesirable result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
select * from cdr
WHERE DATE(calldate) BETWEEN '20121201' AND '20121203';
```

Comment: Watch out, this will kill your performance on big tables, since the index won't work anymore.

Comment: This answer ignores indexes, and is a bad practice.
You should consider using the field value as-is and convert your dates using a format.
You should use @Rohit Suthar 's answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this query -**

```
SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE calldate BETWEEN str_to_date('2012-12-01','%Y-%m-%d') AND str_to_date('2012-12-03','%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: This one actually works and is good practice since it will convert the dates using the given format and use indexes.

Comment: if I wanted to add a timestamp in as well how would I do that.
`str_to_date('2017-10-20 14:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')`

Answer (score -1):

The above will work great. If you wanted to add extra conditions, normal Boolean logic works with date/time as well so you could do something like

```
...
where DATE(calldate) < '20121201' AND DATE(calldate) >= '20121203' OR DATE(calldate) = '20121205'
```

Just a simple example.